# Using MediatR without CQRS

Tags: .net-core, cqrs, mediatr

I'm thinking about using MediatR in my .NET 7 web application because I like that it helps keeping Controllers thin. This way, assuming I wanted to switch from a "classic" web application with razor views to a .NET 7 Web API with another FrontEnd, I could reuse much more BackEnd code.

In many examples I found, I've seen that MediatR is used together with CQRS. The separation between commands and queries would be an overkill for my rather small web application. Would it also be possible to use MediatR without CQRS, just to obtain thin Controllers?

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you how you consume the contract Mediator gives you. You don't have to conform to all the interfaces

In the simplest of examples, you can just fire off a command and put all your logic in there, if that meets your needs

```cs
public async IActionResult Get(SomeCommand command)
{
    await _mediator.Send(command);
    return Ok();
}
```

Then your command can do all the querying

```cs
public class SomeCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<SomeCommand , bool>
{
    public SomeCommand Handler(/* Inject anything you need here, such as databases */) {}

    public Task<bool> Handle(SomeCommand command)
    {
        // Do anything you need in here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm thinking about using MediatR in my .NET 7 web application because I like that it helps keeping Controllers thin.

One thing that MediatR does, is injecting dependencies into the constructors of your handlers - this saves a lot of code. This can actually also be done with [IGet](https://github.com/dotnet-IGet/IGet), a much thinner library with which you can probably create all you need - without MediatR.

```
public void OnGet([FromServices] IGet i, int id)
{
    var result = i.Get<MyQueryHandler>().Handle(id);
    // do something with the result.
}
```

> The separation between commands and queries would be an overkill for my rather small web application. Would it also be possible to use MediatR without CQRS, just to obtain thin Controllers?

Yes, you can use MediatR without CQRS. MediatR does not have a hard relation with CQRS although many people seem to talk about the distinction between queries and commands (in videos and courses) when talking about MediatR.